# Is it possible to update the order item quantity in Magento?

Tags: magento-1.7, php

I want to update the ordered product quantity from the sales order view page (admin side). I have added a new button and actions for update order quantity. But I don't know what are the tables needs to updated for this. or else is there any other solution?(without creating new order concept).

I already gone through below one.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12563078/is-it-possible-to-update-order-items-quantity-in-magento

Thanks

Comment: I don't have a solution, but you shouldn't do that. Orders shouldn't be changed. You can choose to edit the order. This will cancel the current order and create a new one. There you can change the qty of each item.

Comment: @Marius Here no payment is going on. Free only. so i need to change the Quantity alone. what are the tables i need to update?.

Comment: Look into `sales_flat_order_item`.

Comment: Yes, why dont you load the orders items by using `$order->getAllItems();` and do something like `$item->setQty(123);` in a foreach?

Answer (score 1):

So via the admin area you can normally edit orders that are not completed. On the order overview page you should see a button `Edit`. What this will do is cancel the old order and simply let you create a new order. Here you can change the quantity that has been ordered.